# Sent Org CloudTrail logs to CloudWatch to Non-Managment Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have an Organization setup in AWS and have a `Management` account and also a `Sec` Account. I have ***Delegated Admin of CloudTrail*** **from** the `Management` account **to** the `Sec` Account.

In the `Sec` account I then setup an `Organization` `CloudTrail` and all logs are been delivered to an `S3` bucket. This all works fine.

I would like to setup the streaming of the `CloudTrail` `logs` to `CloudWatch` but in the `Sec` Account this option is greyed out as seen below
[image]

If I log back into the `Management` account this option is NOT greyed out and can setup this up.
[image]

This would mean that the `CloudWatch` logs would be in the `Management` Account and the `CloudTrail` logs in the `Sec` Account which is not what I want.

Why is the option to setup `CloudWatch` logs in the `Sec` account greyed out and is there a way round this? Is it possible to have an `Organization` `Trail` setup to deliver the logs in the `Sec` Account and also to get those logs streamed into `CloudWatch` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Creating a trail for your organization in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/creating-an-organizational-trail-in-the-console.html):

> The delegated administrator account cannot currently configure a
> CloudWatch Logs log group using the console, because the console
> operation is not supported. The delegated administrator account must
> use the AWS CLI or CloudTrail APIs to create an organization trail
> with a CloudWatch Logs log group.

So, from the delegated administrator account (Sec Account in your case) you can't configure the CloudWatch log group through the console, but you can do it through the AWS CLI ([create-trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/create-trail.html)). Example:

```
aws cloudtrail create-trail --name 'trail name' --s3-bucket-name 's3 bucket name' --is-multi-region-trail --is-organization-trail --cloud-watch-logs-log-group-arn 'log group arn' --cloud-watch-logs-role-arn 'role arn'
```